# Android In-App-Billing RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS with empty JSON!

Tags: android

Hey folks,
I am slightly modified the dungeons example for the Android In-App-Billing SDK article.  I am having trouble with the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request.  I first make a legitimate purchase and that goes fine, I get a call to onPurchaseStateChange with no issue.  However, when I try to use RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request, I was expecting to get a constructed verified list of purchases, but when I trace it, the JSON returned is verified just fine, but contains no transactions!  Within Security.java in the Dungeons example you see this code in the verifyPurchase method:

```
    if (Consts.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Parsing JSON object");
    }
    JSONObject jObject;
    JSONArray jTransactionsArray = null;
    int numTransactions = 0;
    long nonce = 0L;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(signedData);

        // The nonce might be null if the user backed out of the buy page.
        nonce = jObject.optLong("nonce");
        jTransactionsArray = jObject.optJSONArray("orders");

        if (jTransactionsArray != null) {
            numTransactions = jTransactionsArray.length();
        }

        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSON Array has " + numTransactions + " transactions");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS?  Isn't it supposed to return a verified list of purchases just like REQUEST_PURCHASE through the onPurchaseStateChange?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have to look much closer.  The RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS is meant to be used with MANAGED product ids.  I was purchasing an UNMANAGED item.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type