# Why restore transactions (in-app billing) returns not signed data?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am testing that with reserved product ID (*android.test.purchased*). Is it managed or unmanaged item? Should RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS [be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256048/android-in-app-billing-restore-transactions-with-empty-json) with managed item only?

I've uploaded apk signed with release key to android market (not published) and testing the same on my device with debug version of application. According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html), it should return signed data.
I use test account on the device, not developer's account (test account is added to the list of test accounts).

Comment: Hey LA_
did your problem solved ??
I am also stuck over the same... Please help if you have solution for In-app purchase for managed products.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been experimenting with In-app billings and I discovered that RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS works with only managed items (this is explicitly confirmed on Google In-app billing site). Further, you cannot restore transactions for reserved Product IDs. I had to purchase a real item to test how restore works.

I may be wrong but that is what I found.

Comment: Ok, the testing with real items is the best approach.

Comment: Yes, you can only restore for Managed items.  Unmanaged items are not stored on Google servers.